# Call to UTL_I18N.string_to_raw via ODP.Net Managed Provider results in a lossy character set conversion exception being thrown

Tags: c#, oracle, internationalization, odp.net-managed

I'm trying to store encrypted unicode text in an Oracle `RAW` field.
Before encryption I'm converting the string to a raw byte array as `AL32UTF8`, for the sake of efficiency.
(`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `AL16UTF16`).

A `LOSSY_CHARACTERSET_CONVERSION` (`ORA-12713`) exception is being thrown from the UTL_I18N package.

I am deliberately setting `NCharConversionException = true` to have it throw the exception rather than having the lossy conversion 'greek' the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample using Dapper for convenience.
The NVarchar2 parameter bind without the call to string_to_raw works correctly.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// using Dapper;
    /// using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Test, Explicit]
    public void Dapper_Sql_NLS_StringToRaw_ReturnValue_RefCursor_SmokeTest()
    {

        var parms = new OracleDynamicParameters();
        var cn = ApiThreadContext.Current.Connection.DbConnection as OracleConnection;

        OracleGlobalization og = cn.GetSessionInfo();
        og.NCharConversionException = true; //throws LOSSY_CHARACTERSET_CONVERSION
        cn.SetSessionInfo(og);

        var expected = "Шон";

        parms.Add(":in_plain", expected, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        parms.Add(":rc", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        //'Шон'
        var result = cn.Query<dynamic>(
            "select utl_i18n.string_to_raw(:in_plain, 'AL32UTF8') from dual",
            //"select :in_plain from dual",
            parms,
            commandType: CommandType.Text
        );

    }
```

### Client side

Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1
.Net 4.6 Full
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` 4.12.1.2400 (the latest).

#### OracleGlobalization Settings:

```
{Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleGlobalization}
Calendar: "GREGORIAN"
Comparison: "BINARY"
Currency: "£"
DateFormat: "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"
DateLanguage: "ENGLISH"
DualCurrency: "€"
ISOCurrency: "UNITED KINGDOM"
Language: "ENGLISH"
LengthSemantics: "BYTE"
NCharConversionException: true
NumericCharacters: ".,"
Sort: "BINARY"
Territory: "UNITED KINGDOM"
TimeStampFormat: "DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF"
TimeStampTZFormat: "DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR"
TimeZone: "Europe/London"
```

I haven't set an `NLS_LANG` environment variable on the client because that should be covered by the above.  (I haven't checked if it has any effect on the managed provider in any case).

### Server

#### NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_LANGUAGE                ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY           UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_CURRENCY            £
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY            UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET            WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_CALENDAR                GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       ENGLISH
NLS_SORT                    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT         HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       €
NLS_COMP                    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     FALSE
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION       10.2.0.5.0
```

#### V$VERSION

```
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

#### Client-side error stack:

```
Test 'UddFixture.Dapper_Sql_NLS_StringToRaw_SmokeTest' failed:
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-12713: Character data loss in NCHAR/CHAR conversion
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_I18N", line 321
ORA-06512: at line 1
    at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
    at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    Core\Connectivity\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs(1631,0): at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__61`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    Core\Connectivity\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs(1506,0): at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
    UddFixture.cs(330,0): at UddFixture.Dapper_Sql_NLS_StringToRaw_SmokeTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

In earlier days I also used `OracleGlobalization` object, however I faced several bugs. I clearly recommend not to use it!

Maybe instead of `UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW`, function `ASCIISTR`, resp. `UNISTR` could be an option for your problem:

```
SELECT ASCIISTR('Шон') FROM dual;

\0428\043E\043D

SELECT UNISTR('\0428\043E\043D') FROM dual;

Шон
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion Wernfried.  I do need to take the internationalisation into account, because the clients (and potentially the server as well) may have different i18n settings.  You have pointed to a good workaround for now though, so I am going to upvote your answer rather than accepting it. I am going to use UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw() and make it store the supplied characterset byte array, as we are already storing the source characterset.

Comment: Yes but don't use OracleGlobalization object. Select from `V$NLS_PARAMETERS`, resp. call `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_...`

Comment: OK, but even if I do that rather than having `OracleGlobalization` do it for me, I am still encountering the issue.  I am only setting `NCharConversionException = true` i.e.  `NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP` to force it to throw when a lossy conversion occurs - my actual problem is that it should be able to convert to `AL32UTF8` via the ODP.Net Managed provider, and this is not happening correctly.